# Oracle: Export related data

Tags: oracle11g

I'm looking for a way to export related data spread over several tables, and to import that data in another schema. I'm working with an Oracle 11g Database.

To simplify my case I have tables A, B and C where B has a foreign key on A, and C has a foreign key to B. Having 1 entry in A, I would like to extract all entries relating to this entry from A, B and C and insert them into another schema. Please keep in mind that in my real-world scenario its not A, B and C, but 102 separate tables (don't ask, not my design ;-)).

What I am looking for is a tool that will use the knowledge of the relations between the tables to do the export, without the need for me to specify which tables are connected through which fields.

Is there a way to do that and stay sane?

Answer (score 2):

Data pump will let you supply a predicate per table for extracting the data, so it's a "simple" matter of relating each table to the one that specifies the data for which related data is to be exported. Typically the predicate would be something like "customer_id in (select customer_id from customers).

Comment: Like I said, I have some 100 tables with nearly 400 foreign keys over which the data I am interested in is distributed. So I would love a tool which can do the export based on the databases knowledge of the relations between the tables. If I understand you correctly, I would have to provide the relations myself for every table with data pump, this could lead to a seriously bad day for me ;-)

Comment: I'd hope that you could generate a large part of it with queries against the data dictionary. It wouldn't be pain free, but at least you've got the constraints in there.